# Gendakenexperiments to convince me these facts

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I am a very beginner learning physics. Here are three very counterintuitive facts I have learn't (and it's counterintuitive because I can't test it at home with everyday equipments):

**Fact-1**: In a seesaw, if both sides are balanced, then they are balanced at any angle. I mean that when the seesaw is parallel to the ground and if it is balanced, then it would remain balanced at an arbitrary angle with the ground.

This is seeming to me *very* counterintuitive. I am imagining that if you are balanced at parallel, then if you tilt, then immediately you will tilt all the way down - you can't stay balanced at an arbitrary angle.

**Fact-2:** Newton's first law (or whatever that law which was used in fifth chapter of the first volume of Feynman), which states that if you push an object by an arbitrarily small force, given no friction, it would march off to infinity in the direction without stopping.

This is also seeming to me *very* counterintuitive. I mean almost all regular everyday objects doesn't behaves like this, right ?

So, either give some gendakenexperiment or some real life example which would convince me those two facts.

Comment: Gedankenexperiments are not ever replacements for actual experiments. Indeed, what they are is a way of doing *theory*: we set up a particular clear set of conditions and think through what a *theory* implies under those conditions. On their own they prove nothing.

Comment: That said, seesaws are generally constructed to be unstable (with the center of mass above the center of rotation) like a beam balance. In class I have my students do balancing activities with a stable arrangement (CoM under the center of rotation) which tends back to horizontal, and I have a variant that is almost perfectly neutral which *will* balance at arbitrary angles.

Answer (score 0):

> In a seesaw, if both sides are balanced, then they are balanced at any angle. I mean that when the seesaw is parallel to the ground and if it is balanced, then it would remain balanced at an arbitrary angle with the ground.

Put a large strong box on the ground (Earth's surface) and underneath it,  support it on 4 hydraulic jacks, that you can move vertically to tip the box up at one edge and down at the other. Then lift the box up parallel with the ground.

Then build your seesaw on top of that box. Balance it parallel to the top surface, after putting the pivot point at the center of the box.

Finally, slowly raise one side of the box by extending the jacks and lowering the two on the other side.

Can you see that the seesaw will remain parallel to the Earth's surface, even though the box is tilted to any arbitrary angle?

> Newton's first law (or whatever that law which was used in fifth chapter of the first volume of Feynman), which states that if you push an object by an arbitrarily small force, given no friction, it would march off to infinity in the direction without stopping.

Given no friction obviously implies that nothing can stop it moving. This idea is used in every space probe, you don't need to keep the rocket engine running once you achieve a certain velocity.

Now imagine that to avoid solar radiation overheating  one side of the probe, you fire a tiny tiny thruster for a  nanosecond, in order  to initiate a very slow rotation, which will go on forever, as there is nothing to stop it continually rotating around a central axis that is parallel to its direction of travel.

(A "barbecue roll" that was performed by the Apollo missions to the moon.)

Answer (score 0):

> (1) In a seesaw, if both sides are balanced, then they are balanced at any angle. I mean that when the seesaw is parallel to the ground and if it is balanced, then it would remain balanced at an arbitrary angle with the ground.

An experiment :

Construct a T rod with a flat immovable perpendicular surface. Your  seesaw  has  a short base that can sit on a lazy susan, and the lazy Susan on the top of the T. Stick the  rod on a steep hillside, check that the top of the T is horizontal ,   and balance the seesaw-lazy_susan arangement on top. The angle to the ground changes when the lazy suzan is rotated. observe.

(There is a caution on this, that it depends on g being constant. For huge structures on large hillsides there will be tiny differences in g, depending on the mass below and then this will not hold.)